# How do I structure this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, `user`, `conversation`, and `conversation_participant` with the rows:

**user** 
`id`

**conversation** 
`id`
`type`

**conversation_participant** 
`conversation_id`
`user_id`

(`type` indicates that it is a "private," 1-1 conversation, i.e., ensuring that user1 and user2's conversation is delineated from a group conversation involving, for example, user1, user2, and user3. type=0 is private, type=1 is a group.)

Regardless, how can I best structure a query that determines if a private conversation between two users (user_id=1 and user_id=2) exists? I am tempted to do something like this (I am very new to SQL, mind you):
     `SELECT conversation_participant.conversation_id FROM conversation_participant WHERE user_id=1` ...but I'm pretty certain this is off to an unfortunate start.

What is the most concise way to manage a situation like this with queries from multiple tables that are all interconnected in this fashion? I assume it's relatively simple, and if there are any good readings on this that you may know of, they would be much appreciated as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly that you are looking for conversations between two specific known user ids:

```
select c.id
from conversation_participant cp1
inner join conversation_participant cp2
    on cp1.conversation_id=cp2.conversation_id and cp2.user_id=2
inner join conversation c
    on cp1.conversation_id=c.id and c.type=0
where cp1.user_id=1;
```

In English, find ids of conversations where:

user_id 1 is a participant (from and where clauses)

and user_id 2 is a participant in the same conversation (first join clause)

and that conversation is of private type (second join clause).

Comment: Why is exactly meant by "conversation_participant cp1" ? Would that be the user_id for the first user?

Comment: cp1 and cp2 are both aliases for (potentially different rows of) conversation_participant; you need to alias at least once to join the table on itself.

Comment: von v. also mentioned an alias. I'll have to look into that, but regardless, thanks for explaining as well. Makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the user id of two people as you mentioned as an example then you can do this:

`select count(DISTINCT c.id)
from conversation c
inner join 
(select * from conversation_participant cp
where cp.user_id in (1,2)) cp
on cp.conversation_id = c.id
where c.type=0`

That will give you the number of conversations two people have between them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you quickly explain what is meant by "conversation c inner..."?The "conversation c" part doesn't make sense to me. If "c" is short for conversation, then the "conversation conversation inner join." I'm missing something..

Comment: It's an alias, you can also do it as from conversation AS c

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    conversation, 
    conversation_participant
WHERE conversation.id = conversation_participant.conversation_id
    AND conversation.type = 0
```

This should get you the results you need.  If you're running phpMyAdmin, test it out in the SQL tab and see what it outputs.

This will only show you the number of times a private conversation has occurred, if you want to see 'who' is having these conversations you'll need to lengthen out the join to include the users (I'm assuming you have more columns in the User table than just ID).

Comment: Yes, my user table has numerous other values that I left out for the purposes of this question. But thank you, I will try this out. It makes sense to me looking at it, I just need to read and experiment more with sql.